# Using semantic-release to publish to both github and npmjs

Tags: node.js, github, semantic-release

We are in the process of migrating from npmjs to GitHub Packages for our private npm packages. To try and smooth this process, I am trying to have our CI process publish packages to both registries while projects make the switch. We've been using pretty vanilla semantic-release to do our versioning/publishing and I'm trying to preserve that but keep getting stuck trying to publish to more than one place.

My first attempt had a workflow that went:

1. build/test/etc.
2. `npx semantic-release` with NPM_CONFIG_REGISTRY={github} and appropriate creds
3. `npx semantic-release` with NPM_CONFIG_REGISTRY={npmjs} and appropriate creds

This results in an error in step 3 because semantic-release tries to re-tag/release to github and fails because it already did that in step 2.

My second attempt was:

1. build/tests/etc.
2. `npx semantic-release` (same github settings as previously)
3. `npm publish` with npmjs settings

This works *if step two did a release* - step 3 pushes the just-created release to npmjs and all is well. However, if step 2 did **not** do a release (typically because there were no commits that should cause one based on semantic-releases rules), step 3 ends up trying to re-publish whatever the previously released version was, resulting in an error.

Googling for topics related to "publishing to multiple registries with semantic-release" doesn't seem to yield much, so I'm also wondering if I'm just going about this migration the wrong way. Alternative suggestions welcome.

Comment: You may try using: https://github.com/amanda-mitchell/semantic-release-npm-multiple